# Replacing the word(case senstitive) in a file

Tags: linux, bash, sed, replace

I am new to linux, I have one 200 lines in a file. In that file I need to replace the specific word
eg: **existing word: foo
    New word : bar**
I read some blogs...i understood it can be done with `sed`. But I do not know how to do that with a shell script

```
sed 's/foo/bar/' /path to a file
```

I need to write a script, I do not know how to give the file as an input or should I store in a variable and change the specific word.

The script should change the specific word as well as the file name
eg: Input File name: cat home.txt (word to be replaced -->cat)
OutPut Filename: Dog home.txt(Cat should be replaced with Dog)

Kindly help!

Comment: May the file also contain the string `foo` as a _substring_ of a word that should _not_ be modified, for example `food`, `foobar` or `my-foo`?

Comment: sed can read from standard input or take a filename as argument. These work: `sed 's/foo/bar/' < "file"` or `sed 's/foo/bar' "file"`.

Comment: @Kusalananda No the file doesn't contain substring...its only foo..sed command should reolace the exact word..and it should be case senstitive

Comment: @Devon yes , it works like giving the file as an input, but in my case i  need to replace in case senstitive...how can i do it with sed

Comment: Do you plan on editing the file in-place? Doing it in a script is no different than doing it on the command line.

Comment: @Nasir yes, i got it...Is it possible to edit the file name as well as the contents in a same time
eg:file name: cat.txt (changes to be done: existing word: cat Replcae with  Dog)
When i run the script..file name shoud; also be changed to dog.txt

Comment: Yes, although it will need a different command. To get what you need, add a sample of what you are working with and the expected output so that there is a better of idea of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @NasirRiley I have edited my question...kindly hwlp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the string `foo` with `bar` then you could use this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# the pattern we want to search for
search="foo"
# the pattern we want to replace our search pattern with
replace="bar"
# my file
my_file="/path/to/file"
# generate a new file name if our search-pattern is contained in the filename
my_new_file="$(echo ${my_file} | sed "s/${search}/${replace}/")"
# replace all occurrences of our search pattern with the replace pattern 
sed -i "s/${search}/${replace}/g" "${my_file}"
# rename the file to the new filename
mv "${my_file}" "${my_new_file}"
```

Please be aware that if the search pattern matches parts of a word those parts are also substituted e.g.:

"I have a caterpillar."

with a search string of "cat" and a replace string of "dog", would become

"I have a dogerpillar."

Avoiding this a unfortunately not fully trivial.

Comment: Thank u for your answer...Is it possible to make case sensitive?
foo -->bar
Foo--Bar

Comment: am getting the error while reneming the file "No such file or directory"
Can u pls help me

Comment: When you are adding the -x flag to the first line of the script (`#!/bin/bash -x` ) then you are able to see which commands are executed. This should give you a hint about the problem.

Comment: thank u....Could you please help me with the case  senstitive...
For eg: In the same command sed should be able to replace both small and caps

Comment: for eg: foo -- >bar Foo -->Bar. How to do that

Comment: GNU `sed` has a very good documentation regarding all flags for instance in your case https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-case-insensitive_002c-regular-expression